# How to ONLY pause an IF statement, not the entire code Python

Tags: python

So I have a game that requires the player to become immune to damage for 1 second, otherwise, the code wold instantly kills the player. The way I'm doing it is by checking if the enemy and player are colliding in an IF statement and then taking 1 away from health. The issue is that if I use the "pause" feature my entire code freezes for 2 seconds, I only need this single IF loop to freeze.

Thankyou Alex!

Comment: I'd set a parameter such as `is_immune_until` 1 second into the future. Then before removing health check if currently immune

Answer (score 0):

Like user1558604 said, you should make a boolean called is_immune set to false. When you take damage, set it to true, and set it to false after one second, and before removing health from the player, checking if the player is immune or not.

```
is_immune = False
if player_is_hit:
    if not is_immune:
        player_health -= 1 # Remove 1 from health
        is_immune = True
        # Wait one second
        is_immune = False
```

Comment: but what would make it wait 1 second?

Comment: @AlexTheTech import the time module using import time, then do time.sleep(1) to wait for one second